# Java Application in snap / snappy / snapd

Tags: java, snap, ubuntu-core

I have a self contained application that has it's own startup script, executable jar and the required jre.

tree path:

```
/opt/orangecalc/jre/<files / binaries / libraries> <100+ files>
/opt/orangecalc/icon/oc.png
/opt/oraclecalc/icon/oc.desktop
/opt/oraclecalc/bin/oc_v1.5.6.jar
/opt/oraclecalc/bin/default --> oc_v1.5.6.jar <link>
/opt/oraclecalc/bin/oc_run <sh script launcher>
```

My question is how do you create a snap package from that, all examples are using GIT but I am not it's local files only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dump plugin might help here. It can take a directory (or compressed archive, and many other forms) and literally 'dump' them into the snap, wholesale.

You would still need some wrapping around that, including the necessary jre/jdk and possibly set some environment variables, like JAVA_HOME, but I think the dump plugin is what you're after.

https://snapcraft.io/docs/reference/plugins/dump